# help me to write text on the center of image using PHP GD

Tags: php, math, gd

This one is empty image before writing

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?php
function LoadJpeg($imgname)
{
    $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);

    $grey = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 0);

    // The text to draw
    $text = 'http://www.stackoverflow.com';

    // Replace path by your own font path
    $font = 'CONSOLA.TTF';

    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgname);

    // wants to know how to use this width/height dynamically //

    imagettftext($im, 20, 45, 200, 450, $grey, $font, $text);

    return $im;
}

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

$img = LoadJpeg('Blue_hills.jpg');

imagejpeg($img);
imagedestroy($img);
?>
```

Image after writing text on it

[image]

What I want is vertically and horizontally center the text on 45 degree. Please help me on this. Thanks for you all.

Comment: I hate writing on photos. Especially urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [imagettfbbox](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php) function to retrieve the dimensions the text rendering *would* require. Then use that information to calculate the x,y coordinate you should target within the destination image for the text to be centered respective to the width/height.

Answer (score 0):

I know very little about PHP (I'm making this up as I go along).

I'd recommend making a new square image, setting it to have a transparent background with imagecolortransparent().  Then write the text to the transparent image.

Next I'd try using imagecopyresized() to copy and scale the text to the new window.  Use the minimum of the original's height and width for the destination size.  The offset would be something like (max($width, $height)-min($width, $height))/2.  Apply the offset to whichever dimension is greater.